# React Native: Build a "Select Item from List" component

Tags: list, user-interface, select, react-native, picker

I want to build a "Picker Menu" inside a screen. I think the time picker popup components are not smooth enough to use, because they require extra clicks instead of just dragging to the wanted element.

The component should **return the selected value** + change the color of the selected value. I thought of ListView/ ScrollView, but I couldn't find a way to get that working yet.

Below: A great gimp graphic to show what the goal is, placing the Android Time Picker inside the screen as visual example.

[That's what it could look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CKJDi.png)

Any ideas where to start? How can I build something like this with the React-Native components?

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Comment: No, I'm not looking for anyone to write code for me, but to give me general advise which library I could use or where to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [react-native-wheel-picker](https://github.com/wusuopu/react-native-wheel-picker) or [react-native-wheel-picker-android](https://github.com/ElekenAgency/ReactNativeWheelPickerlibrary). These libraries provide wheel picker without opening any popup.

Comment: https://github.com/lesliesam/react-native-wheel-picker did it for me. The others were bugged on RN 0.49.5

Comment: @Sirhennihau - lesliesam's wheel-picker isn't a DateTime-picker. Any suggestions towards getting a datetimepicker?