# How to use a "Spinner" mode "DatePickerAndroid" without any dialog/modal/popup in react native?

Tags: android, react-native, datepicker

Look at the below image, you may get a clear view of this.

[image]

so how to achieve this spinner date picker without any popup/dialog/modal in a simple screen with some other Views?

I googled throughout the web but didn't find any suitable answer/suggestion relative to it.

Answer (score 1):

As i have also answered here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/48036907/1854129

You can use [react-native-wheel-picker](https://github.com/wusuopu/react-native-wheel-picker) or [react-native-wheel-picker-android](https://github.com/ElekenAgency/ReactNativeWheelPickerlibrary). These libraries provide wheel picker without opening any popup.

Comment: your mentioned libraries are actually looking like a wheel roller. But as I'hv mentioned above what I need, which is the actual view of the spinner date picker which is a native component in android's material-ui, so as in react-native.
So I need a ditto for this, but not in popup/dialog.
Thank You :)

Comment: Has anyone tried to work with react-native-wheel-picker lib? I am running into issues while installing.